# Advantages and disadvantages of OO code in a typical web application context

Tags: php, oop, web-applications

I'm interested in hearing about advantages and disadvantages of developing a web application using the OOP paradigm instead of Procedural.

I am **NOT** interested in

- OOP vs Procedural
- Contexts other than a typical web application, meaning a distributed application where a client makes an HTTP request to a server

My question is motivated by the fact that I've been developing a web application running on my company's Intranet, and would like this application to be "easily" maintainable by the person who will replace me, eventually, so that the application stay and is not replaced by some over abstracted over engineered paid solution a very few people will enjoy working with.

I posted [some bits of my application source](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43190/intranet-php-application) for review at codereview from wich I didn't get a lot of feedback. I then posted [a link](http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1zbwq1/php_application_code_review/) to my post on codereview over at reddit/r/PHP that didn't go really well.

For now, I am under the impression that the vast majority of the "web development" community have decided that OO is the way to go. I'm having a difficult time to understand why BUT I have a feeling that the next dev my company will hire will also be a strong believer in developing OO for a web application as it seems to be the norm nowadays.

I would like to agree with them and join the bandwagon, can someone try and explain to me the advantages and disadvantages of OOP in the typical context of a web application.

While doing some research I came accross this [really interesting comment](http://www.debugmagazine.com/freelancing-tips-tricks/procedural-vs-object-oriented-php-programming#comment-25215) and [this one too](http://www.debugmagazine.com/freelancing-tips-tricks/procedural-vs-object-oriented-php-programming#comment-21131), wich makes it even harder for me to make the switch.

A small quote from one of the comments:

> OOP is for people who can’t properly engineer software or for competent programmers who are involved in very large or complex non-web project. If I were to write an event-driven game to run on a PC, I would not choose procedural programming.

Comment: The fact the guy who you quote claims the person running phpclasses is "competent" pretty much made it clear he has no clue what he's talking about. For what it's worth, I would say the benefits of using OOP for web development are pretty much similar as using OOP for any kind of development.

Comment: Just use what you're comfortable with. OOP or procedural, who cares.

Comment: @JaniHartikainen I do not know the person you are talking about or his "developer skills", but I doubt that praising someone is an indication of one's skills in a given domain.

Comment: @Bart the next dev my company hire might, this is important to me, either I need to backup my way of doing things with strong arguments (I already have some) or I need to refactor my application using the OOP paradigm.

Comment: @teuna phpclasses is pretty much a joke.. the quality is just so appalling that it's unbelievable anyone uses it. This is why it's hard for me to take anyone seriously who would praise anyone involved with it.

Comment: @teuna If the next dev comes along he can easily maintain it. You could even mention it in the job description and hire accordingly. It's really a non issue. The code will only be hard to work with if you write poor quality, undocumented spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

The selling point of a lot of web application frameworks these days is it is an MVC framework. You have the Controller that interfaces with the View and the Model. The model is your business and data layer which contains business objects/entities/data objects - well basically objects that communicate with each other using messages. The objects themselves are restricted to what it is unique to it and only what it can do.

These boundaries/restrictions somewhat make it easier for other people to understand your code and how to modify it. It also helps in unit testing each one of these layers separately.

I suppose if you wanted Rapidly developed application with the controller querying the database and sending information to the view, you could do that too. But the only way to test would be to run the application, check if something breaks, fix, restart it, again test.. You would not be saving a lot of time.

**EDIT**

You are using a single controller which has business logic in it. But your model looks very much like what an OO model should be. So the question I'd ask is, what happens if I break this controller to be domain specific? I would then have to create a UserController and a DepartmentController and UserController renders all views related to CRUDing Users. Is that worth the trouble? Absolutely. Someone else could jump in and work on AdminController or ReportingController, whatever your application needs without having to worry about changes you are making to this controller.

And if one of you colleagues wants to see some changes done to the Department section, you don't need to worry about the rest.

Comment: My [application](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43190/intranet-php-application) implements the MVC pattern but is procedural code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'm not a Php person at all but your self praising question seemed interesting so I researched a bit. My answer is general and is not related to a particular implementation of object oriented technology or web technology.

An object encapsulates the data along with the relevant functionality all in a single piece. it is not to say that you encapsulate your whole application inside a single giant object. A lot is related to how you analyze the problem, identity objects and use them.

A web application as a request-response thingy maybe true in early 90s but now the web apps are mature. It is not necessary to follow a typical request-response scenario. Have you seen a stock tracking app? it does not wait for a request to send a response. it sends whenever the data is available. I worked on the online candidate testing web app which asks questions in fixed amount of time. Once the time is up it ends the test whether the user "requests" to end it or not and results are displayed. Even if it user machine is turned off or there is a network issue, it remembers and never asked the same questions again nor extra time was ever given.

Yes there are bad programmers or "*IT-guys*" who are totally unaware of **OO-analysis**. They program the object oreinted stuf in a very procedural way. The result of their work is a *request-response styled web app with 3 global variables* and a *'z' namespace* but that does not mean that the blame should go to the OO paradigm itself. It goes to the people who didn't understand it so much for apply it at the right place!

Comment: This question is old, at the time most PHP frameworks were using a request object ("made" from PHP global `$_SERVER`) then ran this object through a router object then build a response object to send it back to the client, wait, they still do and I still think it's unnecessary in the context of PHP and HTTP.

My application model layer is fully OO and it's great to work with in services/views but thanks for your answer.

Comment: Before writing this answer, I went thru your responses and comments and it was pretty obvious that you are not open to criticism at all. Even at time when you wrote that code, there are fairly good coding practices being followed by in Php world. We should follow good examples not make bad ones as lame excuses for our scrappy work.

Comment: I am open to criticism just not "follow best practice the end" stuff, because how is it best practice to take a global array and make an object out of it? Why not just use the array as is? This is PHP.